# How to use MySQL and count and rank

Tags: mysql

I'm a MS-SQL Developer, now I use this query (MySQL) ↓

```
SELECT A.place_idx,A.place_id,B.TODAY_CNT,C.TOTAL_CNT FROM CUSTOM_LIST 

AS A

INNER JOIN
(SELECT place_id,COUNT(place_id) AS TODAY_CNT from COUNT_TABLE where DATE(place_date) = DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY place_id)
AS B ON B.place_id=A.place_id

INNER JOIN
(SELECT place_id,COUNT(place_id) AS TOTAL_CNT from COUNT_TABLE GROUP BY place_id)
AS C ON C.place_id=A.place_id
```

The result is:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Comment: Where is Rank? I mean in which table?

Comment: MySQL doesn't support analytic functions.  You can achieve what you want with [user variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/user-variables.html), but it would be easier (if at all possible) to simply `ORDER BY TOTAL_CNT DESC` and add the ranking from within your application code.

Comment: @eggyal adding the rank i easy, once you know how. I had the same problem a while ago. See below.

Comment: Did you search for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490682/how-to-get-the-position-of-sorted-rows-using-mysql-and-php

Comment: none of the current answer returns what's shown in the image! What do you want? Sort the table? Add a rank column and keep the order, or add rank and sort?

Comment: sorry.. i'm korean developer i won't add rank and sort..

Comment: no need to be sorry. It does no matter where you are from or how good your English is as long we figure out what you want ;) Is your question solved with the query below?

Comment: @user1668402 Have a look here sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a2e6/1

Comment: Check this answer, too: [Sorting the Table and getting the position](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18316/sorting-the-table-and-getting-the-position/18326#18326).

Answer (score 4):

Try somethink like this:

```
SELECT ..., C.TOTAL_CNT, (@r := @r + 1) AS rank FROM CUSTOM_LIST, (SELECT  @r := 0) t
...
ORDER BY C.TOTAL_CNT DESC
```

Whole query:

```
SELECT A.place_idx,A.place_id,B.TODAY_CNT,C.TOTAL_CNT, (@r := @r + 1) AS rank 
FROM CUSTOM_LIST AS A, (SELECT  @r := 0) t

INNER JOIN
(SELECT place_id,COUNT(place_id) AS TODAY_CNT from COUNT_TABLE where DATE(place_date) = DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY place_id)
AS B ON B.place_id=A.place_id

INNER JOIN
(SELECT place_id,COUNT(place_id) AS TOTAL_CNT from COUNT_TABLE GROUP BY place_id)
AS C ON C.place_id=A.place_id

ORDER BY C.TOTAL_CNT DESC
```

What if we got two same values in Total_CNT?

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT ..., (@last := C.TOTAL_CNT) AS TOTAL_CNT, 
  IF(@last = C.TOTAL_CNT, @r, @r := @r + 1) AS rank
FROM CUSTOM_LIST, (SELECT  @r := 0, @last := -1) t
...
```

Comment: @PiTheNumber : Can U write total Query ?

Comment: @MRSrinivas: Sure, here you go.

Comment: What if we got Two same values in Total_CNT?

Comment: @Rahul That would be more complicated... :)

Comment: @Rahul I made an update for this but I did not test the code.

Comment: @PiTheNumber have a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function

Answer (score -1):

**Updated**

**RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TOTAL_CNT DESC DESC) AS Rank**

Here I got Another Very Good Solution.:

```
SELECT A.place_idx,A.place_id,B.TODAY_CNT,C.TOTAL_CNT, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TOTAL_CNT DESC) AS Rank FROM CUSTOM_LIST 

AS A

INNER JOIN
(SELECT place_id,COUNT(place_id) AS TODAY_CNT from COUNT_TABLE where DATE(place_date) = DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY place_id)
AS B ON B.place_id=A.place_id

INNER JOIN
(SELECT place_id,COUNT(place_id) AS TOTAL_CNT from COUNT_TABLE GROUP BY place_id)
AS C ON C.place_id=A.place_id
```

Comment: if think `RANK() OVER` is not supported in mysql. Isn't it oracle? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438764/rank-over-in-mysql